# Optimal fan speed for effective cooling

Tags: air-conditioning

I am aware about the basic functioning of a split AC but I am not sure what fan speed provides the optimal performance ignoring the power consumed by the fan motor.
Here are my beliefs :

1. Lower fan speed will cause less airflow through the condenser resulting in less effective cooling and wastage of refrigeration cycles.
2. Higher fan speed will process more room air resulting in better cooling and optimal power consumption.

Comment: Valid statements. So what's the question?

Comment: Traditional outdoor condensing units need 400 CFMs per ton (12,000 btus) of cooling. If this holds true for a minisplit then you need to figure out the CFMs of the fan speeds and compare that against the tons which your compressor can produce. Hint, minisplits should have variable speed compressors so they would adjust based on the cooling demand. A manufacturer shouldn't be installing blowers which outperform the compressor.

Answer (score 2):

For a typical inverter-drive mini-split (variable speed compressor, variable speed fan), the system itself will choose the best speed for both if you set it to auto.

If you have an inefficient constant-speed clunker in mini-split format, that's an entirely different horse-race.

Answer (score 0):

Too many variables there to just deliver an optimum fan speed.  The most important factor is airflow over the evaporator coil.  The optimal fan speed will be whatever speed delivers that amount of airflow.

In the most basic terms, an air conditioner is a heat pump.  Given a coil size and refrigerant temperature, the evaporator coil has a maximum amount of heat it can transfer in a given time.  It is up to the rest of the system (compressor and fan) to make that heat transfer happen.

If we just ignore the compressor/refrigerant part of the system and assume it is operating optimally, the fan speed will still depend on the size of the ducting (if you have any), permeability of filter(s), etc.

Too complicated just to say higher = better, etc.  If you are pushing too much air, you overshoot the capability of the coil to remove heat and at that point you're just making noise.  However, without the ability to measure all those datapoints it is still safer to trend on the side of more airflow vs. less.  Losing efficiency is better than icing up the coil.